# Convert a VARCHAR2 to DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to convert  VARCHAR2 in one column(DATEOLD) to DATE format in another column(DATENEW) in the same table. My VARCHAR2 is in the format YYYYMMDD  Eg.20210728

```
UPDATE SUPPORT 
SET DATENEW = to_date(DATEOLD, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Doesn't seem to work?

Comment: `date` is a data type, not a format. Is the data type of the `DATENEW` column `date`, or is it `varchar2`, and you just want it to use a different format model? Note that "formats" only apply to the string representations of dates; they don't apply to the `date` data type itself.

Comment: "My VARCHAR2 is in the format **YYYYMMDD**" but "to_date(DATEOLD, '**MM/DD/YYYY**')". Its quite strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong format mask, which should be `YYYYMMDD`, based on a string date input like `20210728`.  Try this version:

```sql
UPDATE SUPPORT
SET DATENEW = TO_DATE(DATEOLD, 'YYYYMMDD');
```